# data type mismatch on criteria expression

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have three tables with the exact same data fields and data types. I am trying to create a search form using one combo box for three subforms. I tried changing the String to Integer but I always end up with the same error: "Data type mismatch on criteria expression". What am I doing wrong here.

```
Private Sub cboAlarmSearch_AfterUpdate()
    Dim SpotAlarm As String
    Dim ProgressAlarm As String
    Dim FinalAlarm As String
    Dim strAlarmCriteria As String

    If IsNull(Me.cboAlarmSearch) Or Me.cboAlarmSearch = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please choose an Alarm to search.", vbOKOnly, "Alarm Required"

    Else
        strAlarmCriteria = Me.cboAlarmSearch.Value

        'Alarm search for Spot
        SpotAlarm = "Select * FROM tblSpot WHERE ([Alarm]  = '" & strAlarmCriteria & "')"
        Me.frmSpotSearchSubform.Form.RecordSource = SpotAlarm
        Me.frmSpotSearchSubform.Form.Requery

        'Alarm search for Progress
        ProgressAlarm = "Select * from tblProgress WHERE ([Alarm]  = '" & strAlarmCriteria & "')"
        Me.frmProgressSearchSubform.Form.RecordSource = ProgressAlarm
        Me.frmProgressSearchSubform.Form.Requery

        'Alarm search for Final
        FinalAlarm = "Select * from tblFinal WHERE ([Alarm]  = '" & strAlarmCriteria & "')"
        Me.frmFinalSearchSubform.Form.RecordSource = FinalAlarm
        Me.frmFinalSearchSubform.Form.Requery
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the data type of your [Alarm] field?

Comment: And what is the content of `strAlarmCriteria` ?

Comment: The data type of Alarm is Number. I already found the problem. It is in my quoting. Instead of  ' " & strAlarmCriteria & " ' it should have been " & strAlarmCriteria & ". I also replaced “strAlarmCriteria” to “intAlarmCriteria” just to remind me that it will be holding a Number. Thanks.